# php/javascript problems within facebook iframe canvas

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, canvas

I am new to the whole facebook development, but not new to programming. I have reached my wits end on 2 issues cannot figure out to save my life. I have followed all instructions to the letter.

1. I have a PHP page that contains only "phpinfo();". When I directly navigate to that page in my site (I use Yahoo! web hosting), it returns "PHP version 5.3.6" which is correct. However, when I navigate to the exact same page via facebook canvas, it returns "PHP version 4.3.11". As I am sure you can imagine, this conflict prevents my actual app page from utilizing "facebook.php"  which throws an error regarding T_CONST, T_FUNCTION, T_VAR on line 29. How can I resolve this conflict?
2. To further add to my frustration, nothing in the facebook Javascript SDK is working neither and no errors are reported.

All I am ultimately needing is the user id, the invite friends dialog, and the post to wall dialog. Any ideas? Thanks in advance. Have a great day.

Comment: This makes no sense.  Facebook canvas has nothing to do with your php version ?!!!

Comment: I agree. It is just an iframe & should be nothing special. But, phpinfo(); tells the story. I cannot figure out how to get around that?

Comment: http and https? 
On some machines, it's use different configurations for each protocol.

Comment: I agree with "Hereblur you might have 2 services each one bind a different port. try accessing phpinfo directly but with https !